# How to define a sets using enumeration or Roster Method?

Tags: notation, definition

How to Solve this Union of sets and Intersection i dont understand how to solve this in roster method:

[Union sets problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA97a.jpg)

Comment: No ideas ? Write $A$ and then "compute" $A^C$ subtracting from $U$ the elements of $A$. Then write $C$ and finally "compute" $A^C \cap C$ listing the common elements of the two sets.

Comment: what if A / B^C

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).